# Line-height differences between Firefox and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari, cross-browser

This is driving me a bit nuts...I'm working on a site and trying to get a `<ul>` to render consistently across Safari (v 7.0.1) and Firefox (v 25.0.1). I've simplified the CSS and HTML just about as much as I can... there is still a difference in the distance between the "job title" (the `<a>` tag) and "location" (the `<p>` tag) of several pixels between the two browsers.

Fiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/7BZGU/7/

Here's my code -- is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? I understand browsers render stuff differently, but I'm not sure why two modern browsers have such a difference when dealing with pretty vanilla code...

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="current-openings">
        <h3>Current Openings</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Junior Risk Reporting Analyst</a>
                <p>Chicago, IL</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Trading Data Analyst</a>
                <p>Houston, TX</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#current-openings {
    margin: 30px 0 10px 50px;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

#current-openings h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
}

#main ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 5px;
}

#main ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 4px 0 25px 21px;
}


#main p {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple things that helped the spacing be pretty close!

1. I removed the line height from your ul: having such a low line height will create a jumble of text once the text wraps)
2. set the paragraph's margin automatically by doing this:

   margin: 10px 0px;
3. I believe what you are trying to do is align the bullet image, correct? To do this it is best to use:

   background-position: 0px 10px;

Doing this eliminates the need for line height anyway!

This helps by overriding the initial paragraph styles and setting them specifically, so it works across multiple browsers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have mentioned in my question that I need that line-height to be set that way. I'm using custom bullets on the <li> items and without that line-height the <a> tag text does not line up properly with the bullet. I've tried other fixes (like a negative top margin on the <a>) but can't get them lined up without the line-height setting...

Comment: Maybe include those bullets so I can try to find a better solution for you? Did the margin help at all?

Comment: I've updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7BZGU/9/) with the image I'm using...as you can see, even with the margin there is a big difference between the two browsers with the <p> element...the <a> elements line up across browsers, but it looks like they are rendering the line height differently...I'm curious as to why this is happening and would love to hear what is going on behind the scenes

Comment: PS: I've gotten it pretty close using a position:relative and a negative top value on the <li>'s, but not thrilled with that solution....

Comment: I think I have answered your question. I have edited my answer. Really, it just sounds like you are having a tough time aligning the new image for your bullets! Let me know if this helps! It really is important to completely take out the line height property if it is not necessary (putting it to zero wont do the trick) :)